# Where is the problem about selenium with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

When I run the code it takes about 5-6 sec to execute, after than nothings happens. I get no error, but the code is simply not working. Please, help me fast I've got a project to do in a month.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
opts = Options()
opts.set_headless()
assert opts.headless
browser = Firefox(options=opts)
browser.get("https://duckduckgo.com")
```

Sorry about not knowing enough about stackoverflow. I think I wrote everything to the code entry.

Comment: Do you have geckodriver? If you don't just download it [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't work? Because browser runs in headless mode and you will not see anything.  did you check response?

Comment: your code definitely works. You just use headless option, which means the opened browser will be invisible. Headless browser is just a browser with no GUI to make selenium faster.

Comment: @sertsedat headless won't make it any faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is perfectly **working** for me.

`opts.set_headless()
browser = Firefox(options=opts)`

This operation will create an option which **hide** the browser, then you set this option to you recently created Firefox tab.
Once you open the *duckduckgo* url,

It takes a few seconds to you program to open Firefox, but... you reach the end of your program and you browser is **HIDING**
Check with `top` command and you'll see Firefox still running.
Try to execute the same code but without the `opts.set_headless()` line.

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

Try not use the "headless option":

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
browser = Firefox()
browser.get("https://duckduckgo.com")
```